# MFMailComposeViewController only subject showing

Tags: ios, iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I try to send e-mail from my IOS app but it does not work. I have tried lots of different tutorials, test it on a real iPhone. I have implemented MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, imported MessageUI / MessageUI.h in the h file. When the message is opened the subject is there but not the message itself and not to whom the message should be sent to(Recipient). Both are empty, and the message can not be sent. I do not understand what the problem is I have followed 10 different tutorials but none works. I work in Xcode 7 (objective c).

Comment: Thanks for responding, the problem was that i had to restart my phone. I spend 7h on this :P

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the recipients in the recipient array and pass it to `MFMailComposeViewController`. Like this:

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController* mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [mail setMailComposeDelegate:self];
        [mail setSubject:@"Test Subject"];
        [mail setMessageBody:@"Stannis Baratheon is the one true King....Also this is a test email" isHTML:NO];
        NSArray *arrayOfRecepients = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"test@gmail.com",@"test@yahoo.com",nil];//Add as many email addresses as you want. For single email, add only one email in this array
        [mail setToRecipients:arrayOfRecepients];

        [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
```

I am assuming that you are not adding recipients correctly. I am waiting for your response to Russell's comment to show us your code to correctly determine what is wrong with your code. I will then update the answer if need be.

Answer (score 0):

When i restarded my phone it worked, so if this happends try to restart your IOS device